# temporarly save data from more than 2 gridviews

Tags: aspxgridview

am trying to find a way to temporarily save data from 7 grid views on  the same page before saving.
i have  tried this .

```
        //Store the DataTable in ViewState for future reference 

        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        //Bind the Gridview 
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();

        //Gridview2.DataSource = dt;
        //Gridview2.DataBind();

        //Gridview3.DataSource = dt;
        //Gridview3.DataBind();

        //Gridview4.DataSource = dt;
        //Gridview4.DataBind();

        //Gridview5.DataSource = dt;
        //Gridview5.DataBind();

        //Gridview6.DataSource = dt;
        //Gridview6.DataBind();

        //Gridview7.DataSource = dt;
        //Gridview7.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir you must save your grids data in xml.

You can put all tables into `DataSet` and wirte a xlm file.

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(yourTable);
ds.Tables.Add(yourTable);
ds.WriteXml(fileName);
```

To read data from xml file.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(FileName)
return ds;
```

Try it sir.May be it helps you.